# Apollo Client Chrome Devtools Cache Empty with Angular

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-client

I have an Apollo Angular Client application. I write to the store:

```
const userQuery = this.userGql.document;
this.apollo.getClient().writeQuery({
  query: userQuery,
  data: { user: result.data.login.user },
});
```

This works. I then retrieve the user from the cache and display the data:

```
this.user = this.apollo.getClient().readQuery({
  query: this.userGql.document,
}).user;
```

This also works. However, the entire time my cache in Google Chrome Devtools looks like this:

[image: Dev Tools Cache]

Why is this empty? I'd like to view my cache state debugging. Also, when I go to GraphiQL tab, and select get from cache, it queries the API (I can tell because I don't pass a token and it rejects the request with an unauthenticated error).

Edit, I did set `connectToDevTools` to true just in case:

```
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      dataIdFromObject: object => {
        switch (object.__typename) {
          case 'user':
            return object['username'];
        }
      },
    }),
    connectToDevTools: true,
  };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `connectToDevTools` to `true` inside your Apollo client config?

Comment: I did, Thanks. Modified post to show

Comment: I have the same issue in React. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: I still have this issue.